# Pandas compare index value to corresponding index value to find a percentage match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am trying to compare value associated with the index to values associated with other index and come up with percentage match.

I have the below table :

```
 ColumnA    ColumnB
 TestA      A
 TestA      B
 TestA      C
 TestA      D
 TestB      D
 TestB      E
 TestC      C
 TestC      B
 TestC      E
 TestD      A


Index TestA has values A,B,C,D when compared to Index B which has values D,E we can see only 1 value matches out of possible 5(A,B,C,D,E). Hence match in 20%.

Index TestA has values A,B,C,D when compared to Index C which has values C,B,E we can see only 2 value matches out of possible 5(A,B,C,D,E). Hence match in 40%.

Index TestA has values A,B,C,D when compared to Index D which has values A we can see only 1 value matches out of possible 4(A,B,C,D). Hence match in 25%.

Index TestB has values D,E when compared to Index A which has values A,B,C,D  we can see only 1 value matches out of possible 5(A,B,C,D,E). Hence match in 20%.

Index TestB has values D,E when compared to Index C which has values C,B,E  we can see only 1 value matches out of possible 1(B,C,D,E). Hence match in 25%.
```

....so on.....

The idea is to display the data in matrix format:

```
       TestA    TestB   TestC   TestD
TestA   100     20      40       25
TestB   20      100     25       0
TestC   40      25      100      0
TestD   25      0       0       100
```

The basic code I have written is to iterate through values.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyexcelerate import Workbook
import numpy as np
import time
start = time.process_time()
excel_file = 'Test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=1, index_col=0)
mylist = list(set(df.index.get_values()))
mylist.sort()
for i in mylist:
    for j in mylist:
        L1 = df.loc[i].get_values()
        L2 = df.loc[j].get_values()
        L3 = []
        print(i,j)
        for m in L1:
                if not m in L3:
                    L3.append(m)
                    for n in L2:
                        if not n in L3:
                            L3.append(n)
        L3.sort()
        if i == j:
            print(len(L1)/len(L3)*100)
        else:
            n = 0
            for k in L1:
                for l in L2:
                    if k == l:
                        n = n+1
            print(n/len(L3)*100)
print(time.process_time() - start)
```

how to calculate percentage from here and display the data in the matrix format I was hoping to show.

EDIT1: Updated the code as I can calculate percentage now. I am looking for a way to print this data in matrix format.

EDIT2: The original dataset is about 10k odd unique entries in columnA and 15K odd unique entries in column B. Total number of rows in the sheet is around 40. Not sure if that makes a difference. Just thought it will provide some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use itertools to calculate the product of all unique Col A and then calculate the pct and build a new df:

```
from itertools import product

# for each unique element in colA, build a list of unique elements from ColB
g = (
    df.groupby('ColumnA').ColumnB
    .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
)

# generate a combination of all the lists 
prod = list(product(g, repeat=2))

data = (
    #for each pair of lists, find the number of common elements,
    #then divide by the union of 2 lists. This gives you the pct.
    np.array([len(set(e[0]).intersection(e[1]))/len(set(e[0]).union(e[1])) for e in prod])
    .reshape(len(g), -1)
)

pd.DataFrame(data*100, index=g.index.tolist(), columns=g.index.tolist())

        TestA   TestB   TestC   TestD
TestA   100.0   20.0    40.0    25.0
TestB   20.0    100.0   25.0    0.0
TestC   40.0    25.0    100.0   0.0
TestD   25.0    0.0     0.0     100.0
```

Comment: The code definitely works on the small dataset. I am trying to run it on a larger dataset to check for issues.

Comment: This is definitely going to be much faster than a nested for loop solution. Let me know how it goes on your full dataset.

Comment: agree this is faster than the looping solution. Still hasn't completed reading 40k odd records in my original excel(Approx 1 hour gone). Will let you know how I go.

Comment: This is awesome. I'll accept the answer. Can I get a few lines explaining some of the complex stuff done in the code for my learning ?

Comment: No worries. I've just added some comments to the code. If you run the code line by line it'll be easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I show you the solution I have found:

I have named df to:

```
  df
      ColumnA ColumnB
    0   TestA       A
    1   TestA       B
    2   TestA       C
    3   TestA       D
    4   TestB       D
    5   TestB       E
    6   TestC       C
    7   TestC       B
    8   TestC       E
    9   TestD       A
```

---

**Code:**

```
M=pd.DataFrame(columns=df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist(),index=df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist())
j=len(df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist())
for i in range(len(df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist())):
    my_list=[]
    for k in range(j):
        t1=df.loc[df['ColumnA'].eq(df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist()[i])]['ColumnB']
        t2=df.loc[df['ColumnA'].eq(df['ColumnA'].unique().tolist()[i+k])]['ColumnB']
        M.iloc[i,i+k]=100*t1.isin(t2).sum()/len(pd.concat([t1,t2]).drop_duplicates())
        M.iloc[i+k,i]=100*t1.isin(t2).sum()/len(pd.concat([t1,t2]).drop_duplicates())
    j-=1
```

**Output `M`:**

```
       TestA  TestB  TestC  TestD
TestA    100     20     40   25.0
TestB     20    100     25    0.0
TestC     40     25    100    0.0
TestD     25      0      0  100.0
```

Comment: The code definitely works on the small dataset. I am trying to run it on a larger dataset to check for issues.